# $e^x>x$ for all real $x$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that $e^x>x$ for all real numbers $x$.

For negative $x$ and $x=0$ it is clear, since $e^x>0$ and $x\leq 0$.

For positive $x$, if I graph both $e^x$ and $x$, I can see why it's true, since $e^0=1$, so the graph of $e^x$ starts out at $1$, the graph of $x$ starts out at $0$, and $e^x$ grows faster (exponentially). But how can I make this rigorous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derivatives. Namely $(e^x)'=e^x$ while $x'=1$. Then if $f(x)=e^x-x$ what can you say? Remember that if $f'>0$ then $f$ is strictly increasing. In particular, if $f(0)\geqslant 0$ and $f'>0$ then $f>0$ throughout the ray $x> 0$.

Comment: I apologize I will remove my comment.

Comment: @user71352 I was just giving my opinion, there is no need to remove the comment. Surely the page had a nice exposition on this.

Comment: Oh okay. This question appears to be related to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racetrack_principle